# Android multi jni modules [gradle]

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to know, how to modify build.gradle to make more than one module (`ndk{moduleName}`) from selected `*.c` files. Have anybody done this before? Is this even possible?

Let say I have two classes:

```
public ClassA {
   static { 
      System.loadLibrary("ClassAlib") 
   }

   public native int funcA();
}

public ClassB {
   static { 
      System.loadLibrary("ClassBlib") 
   }

   public native int funcA();
}
```

For both I generated jni headers and created .c files inside src/jni folder. How to modify build.gradle file to make two libs instead of one?

Comment: For now, it looks to me that the only solution you have is to create java lib sub-project, then add that lib to the apps dependencies, but I also think it's an overkill.

Comment: Will you post your Gradle source?  Or at least a simplified version that illustrates what you are doing so that we can see what Gradle features you're using to generate the JNI modules.

Comment: Well it's a misconception to think of these as a multiple libraries. I ended up with multiple .c and .h files and one main.c and *.*.*_natives_MainJNI.h which then include all other files. Maybe it's not the perfect solution but from JNI point it doesn't matter if you have separated modules because they go into static block. You can't load same libs with System.loadLibrary into multiple java Classes because they can be loaded only once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use two option for build.grade:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = [<location for each module>] 
        jniLibs.srcDir '<location for so file>'
    }
}
```